# Do we ever need Observable.just(..) or Observable.fromCallable{...} as we already have Single.just(..) or Single.fromCallable{...}?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, rx-java, rx-java2

In RxJava2, we have `Single` as an Observable that will only generate one and only one data.

One could code

```
Single.just(...)
// OR
Single.fromCallable{ ... }
```

However, in `Observable` we could also do that

```
Observable.just(...)
// OR
Observable.fromCallable{ ... }
```

The different is in `Observable`, we'll have an extra `onComplete` callback once the one and only data is given. Nothing else.

Hence I was wondering do we ever need `Observable.just(..)` or `Observable.fromCallable{...}` since the `Single` version of it should suffice? Is there a scenario where `Observable.just(..)` or `Observable.fromCallable{...}` can achieve (or better than) but not with `Single.just(..)` or `Single.fromCallable{...}`?

Comment: One scenario might be the API uses `Observable` because it's possible (even likely) there will be more than one item, but maybe some implementation only emits one item. Since the implementation is restricted to `Observable` it can use `Observable.just`.

Comment: from the top of my head, I think they're useful if you're chaining things. If the source observable is an `Observable` than you avoid converting things from `Single` to `Observable` or vice-versa.